# i want to use a toggle switch for active inactive status, i want to use in yii2 curd index page, i have added a widget toggle

Tags: yii2

i want to use a toggle switch for active inactive status, i want to use in yii2 curd index page, i have added a widget  toggle

[

```
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
          'template'=>  Toggle::widget(
            [

           /* 'attribute'=>'company_status',*/
                'clientEvents'=>['validate()'],
                "id"=>"stat",
                'name' => 'stat', // input name. Either 'name', or 'model' and 'attribute' properties must be specified.
                //'checked' => 'true',
                'options' => [], // checkbox options. More data html options [see here](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com)
            ]
```

how to change the checked status

Comment: 'how to change the check status' you mean, in javascript?

Comment: no, by default  the checkbox is checked, i want to read the checkbox value, when it is checked or unchecked.

Comment: I understand that by default this checkbox is checked. If you want to read the checkbox value, it will have to be in javascript....